# ubuntu hanging at unpacking linux header 3.13.0-49

Tags: 14.04, apt, upgrade

My Acer desktop with Ubuntu 14.04 was hanging after `sudo apt-get update; sudo apt-get upgrade` at the unpacking of linux header 3.13.0-49. The mouse and screen seemed frozen.

Comment: Is the second command supposed to be `sudo apt-get upgrade`?

Comment: Also. Just try rebooting. Your computer's already frozen, and I can show you how to fix it from Recovery Mode if it doesn't boot.

Comment: sorry, yes edited it above to be `upgrade`.

Comment: Managed to reboot through ssh. Amended above.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I managed to ssh through from another pc, which took forever. The pc was very slow. I managed to kill some processes and then rebooted. Now if I try to log in to my profile from the acer pc it loops back to the log in screen. I can ssh in to the acer though from another pc. I tried to update & upgrade again and it came up with:

```
E: dpkg was interrupted, you must manually run 'sudo dpkg --configure -a' to correct the problem.
```

Thus ran `sudo dpkg --configure -a` and `sudo apt-get update; sudo apt-get upgrade` again. Rebooted and now I can log in using the acer pc. I think the problem was with the memory being full. I have motion cctv software that has been running for a few days and this seems to have loaded the memory which may have caused the crash. This did happen quite suddenly though ( the freeze ) so it could be something else. Needless to say the problem seems to have disappeared.